# Expression expected with a =

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a launcher for my new MMORPG Toontown Rebuilt.
I am making a developer launcher with a special script injector for developers.
However, people could leak the launcher and i want to make it more secure.
I have a system to return access denied to non developers, but it says expression expected on a = sign.

```
If TextBox1.Text Is = "HIDDEN NAME" Or "HIDDEN NAME" Or "HIDDEN NAME" Then
    TextLabel8776.Text = "GRANTED"
Else
    TextLabel8776.Text = "DENIED"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)
End If
```

Comment: `If TextBox1.Text = "HIDDEN NAME" Then`  why did you duplicate the "HIDDEN NAME" part?

Comment: The syntax of your If statement is wrong. It should be `If TextBox1.Text = "HIDDEN NAME" OrElse TextBox1.Text = "HIDDEN NAME" OrElse TextBox1.Text = "HIDDEN NAME" Then`

Comment: Either remove `Is` or `=` sign.

Comment: You should also work on meaningful variable names (`TextLabel8776`)

Comment: Looks like you've got some required reading to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: your "security" protocol will also last about 13 seconds

Comment: hey, hidden name isnt the REAL names, guys. TextLabel8776 is the status counter that will display DENIED or GRANTED. It's a text label though. and no, the source of the launcher for devs will be kept in the team. but if it DOES get leaked, that's there for a reason. Also i have an idea for if anyone adds their name to the protocol.

Comment: Also, I don't know why the strings should be compared. I'm a beginner, so if you could fill me in on why I need it and how to use it, that would be great. Thanks :P

Comment: wooer, thanks for helping, but this happens: InvalidCastExeption was unhandled.

Comment: it doesnt matter **what** the hidden text is, nor **where** it is, its feeble and wont last.  Use @AndrewMorton 's method if there are multiple hidden text possibilities.  there is a reason some comments are upvoted and some are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't combine Is and =, you have to use one or the other
- The way you did the Or doesn't work in VB, it'll try to do bitwise operation.
- In your case, you can use OrElse instead of Or.
- variables properly, it'll help a lot for the futur.
- The number in the Sleep doesn't fix the size of the parameter, it will overflow.
- I highly suggest that you remove the Sleep logic, find an other algorithm.

---

```
If tbHiddenName.Text = "HIDDEN NAME" OrElse tbHiddenName.Text = "HIDDEN NAME" Then
    tbStatus.Text = "GRANTED"
Else
    tbStatus.Text = "DENIED"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) ' Find an other algorithm!
End If
```

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the edit. I don't know why I couldn't display the code properly.

Comment: it gets confused by a code block following a list, just add a HR (`---`) or a line of text like "The code:" in between

Comment: the sleep is to "stop" the code. if you have another way to do so, i'm listening :P

Comment: and TextBox1.Text was the username thing.